# GAM with non-normal noise

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model

I am starting to work with GAM models, and I am trying to figure out the consequences of having non-normal noise. Consider the following example (just note that `Gumbel(-0.57, 1)` is a centered continued distribution with a finite variance, but skewed):

```r
n=1000;
X1=rexp(n); X2=runif(n, 0, 5); Y=-2 + sin(X1) + X2^3 + rgumbel(n, -0.57, 1);

fit=gam(Y~s(X1)+s(X2))
```

So, can I somehow take into account that the noise is non-normal? Do I have to?

**Some motivation:** I am actually trying to estimate the distribution of the noise variables here (as they have a specific interpretation in my problem). So I would like to see something like `fit$residuals` having approximately Gumbel distribution. Is it true though that as $n\to\infty$ we would not reject `ks.test(fit$residuals, Gumbel)`? Or in other words, are the estimations of $\hat{f}_1,\hat{f}_2$ consistent even if we don't have normal noise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mgcv` package can fit generalized additive models from [many families of distributions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/family.mgcv.html) including the [Gumbel distribution](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/gumbls.html).

The authors provide the following example:

````r
library(mgcv)
n <- 400
set.seed(9)

# Smooth function of predictors
f0 <- function(x) 2 * sin(pi * x)
f1 <- function(x) exp(2 * x)
f2 <- function(x) 0.2 * x^11 * (10 * (1 - x))^6 + 10 * (10 * x)^3 * (1 - x)^10

# Generate U[0,1] RVs to plug into smooth functions
x0 <- runif(n)
x1 <- runif(n)
x2 <- runif(n)
x3 <- runif(n)

# Generate response
mu <- f0(x0) + f1(x1)
beta <- exp(f2(x2)/5)
y <- mu - beta * log(-log(runif(n))) ## Gumbel quantile function

# Fit GAM with Gumbel error 
b <- gam(list(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1),~ s(x2) + s(x3)), family=gumbls)
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, do you know how can I fix the second parameter there? I am only modelling the first parameter, and the second is actually a fixed one. Also, do you happen to know why `b$residuals==NULL`? (Sorry if I ask a bit boring stupid questions)

Comment: Change the second formula in gam to contain just an intercept fix the second parameter: `gam(list(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1), ~ 1), family=gumbls)`. You can access residuals with `residuals(b)`.

Comment: yeah, thats what I did. But `residuals(b)` look like they are normally distributed (at least from looking at `hist(residuals(b))`  or by a simple normality test). I don't get it why, I would really say that they should be Gumbel (as residuals are $Y-\hat{\alpha_0}-\hat{f}_1(X_1)-\hat{f}_2(X_2)\approx Gumbel(-0.57, 1)$). So either I am not properly understanding some underlying methodology or this function doesn't do what I want

Comment: Just checked the documentation and mgcv gives deviance residuals by default. To get $Y - \hat{Y}$, you want "response" residuals: `residuals(b, type = "response")`

Comment: Yes, that works. oh, this is great, thanks. Just last question out of curiosity: `summary(b)` gave me the line `(Intercept).1    6.95432    0.02480  280.46   <2e-16 ***`. This should correspond to the second "scale" parameter. We model this parameter even though we know it is $1$. And this estimation is far away $6.95\neq 1$. So one question is- why is this estimation so far away from the true one? Does it represent something else than what I think?

Comment: And the second question- we model the scale parameter even though we know what it is. In limit it shouldn't matter, but is there some way how to say "do not estimate it, its a known constant"?

Comment: I found it actually deep in help() that there is an option for setting `scale=1`. I just hope that scale means the same in gaussian case as in gumbel one. I have a final model `fit <- gam(list(Y ~ s(X1) + s(X2),~1), scale = 1, family=gumbls)` that seems to give a reasonable answering. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2):

You could fit the model, say `m1`, using the `gamlss` R package:

```r
m1 <- gamlss(Y ~ pb(X1) + pb(X2), family = GU)
```

However the parameterisation of gumbel and GU may be different.
You could randomly generate observations using `gamlss` by

```r
mu <- 2 + sin(X1) + X2^3

sigma <- rep(1,1000)

Y <- rGU(1000,mu,sigma)
```

or

```r
Y <- 2 + sin(X1) + X2^3 + rGU(1000,0,1)
```

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't know about this package before. But, would you happen to know what am I doing wrong? I used exactly as you said, so I ended up with `m1$residuals` but they are not Gumbel distributed (not far, but not really). Yes, rGU is differently parametrized, but its just rGU(n, a,b) = -rgumbel(n, -a, b) so it shouldn't cause any problems. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The residuals in `gamlss` are normalised quantile residuals

These residuals have a standard normal distribution for the true model, so compare these residuals with a standard normal distribution.

The easiest way in `gamlss` is

```r
plot(m1)
```

which gives you a histogram and a normal QQ plot of these residuals.

You can also get a de-trended normal QQ plot of the residuals in `gamlss` (called a worm plot) by

```r
wp(m1)
```

I don't think these residuals are available in `gam`. I like the `gamlss` residuals because they are easy to check against a standard normal distribution.

Other residuals like: "deviance", "pearson","scaled.pearson", "working", or "response" are not normally distributed, and so are difficult to check.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It took me a while to find what "normalized quantile residuals" are. It seems that it is reasonable and working, thanks (its working the same way as the answer of @eli) . I have a final question if you don't mind- we model the scale parameter even though we know what it is (gamlss automatically puts `scale~1` so we are estimating it also). Is there some way how to say "do not estimate it, its a known constant one"?

Answer (score 0):

The following command in the `gamlss` R package

```r
m1 <- gamlss(Y ~ pb(X1) + pb(X2), family = GU)
```

fits `Y ~ GU(mu, sigma)` distribution where `mu = pb(X1) + pb(X2)`,  i.e. a smooth function of `X1` + a smooth function of `X2`. The amount of smoothing (or degrees of freedom used for smoothing) is calculated automatically, and `log(sigma)` = constant, because log is the default link function for `sigma` for GU, so `sigma` is also constant, and the constant is fitted.

If you want to fix `sigma` at a specific value, e.g., 2, use

```r
m1 <- gamlss(Y ~ pb(X1) + pb(X2), sigma.start=2, sigma.fix=TRUE, family = GU)
```

If you want to fit a model for `log(sigma)`, use e.g.,

```r
m1 <- gamlss(Y ~ pb(X1) + pb(X2), sigma.fo =~ pb(X1) + pb(X2), family = GU)
```

(Note `sigma.fo` is short for `sigma.formula`.)

Comment: Why did you post 3 separate answers to this question? Also please use code formatting (see the edits to your previous 2 answers for how to format with backticks).

Comment: Thanks. Well, better 3 answers than none. Usually, people use to edit the previous answer, but it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Anyway, yeah, thanks for the answer. It seems that `sigma.fix=TRUE` actually work, I should have first look at the help before asking you (its explained there also)